# Как сделать уведомление с музыкальным плеером внутри?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть служба, благодаря которой у меня проигрываются песни. Кстати, все поля в ней являются статистическими. Я хочу, чтобы она отображал уведомление, при вызове метода listen, которое содержало плеер в себе и на все его кнопки можно было ставить обработчики событий

Comment: [прочитайте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), пожалуйста, как стоит заводить вопросы

Comment: Notification.Action